# When you have two concatenated questions like this, should the second one be in question or statement form?

Tags: grammar, questions

When you have two concatenated questions like this, should the second one be in question or statement form?

Is it:

Should I send it before June, or **should I wait**?

Or:

Should I send it before June, or **I should wait**?

Thank you!

Comment: You have typed them the same way...

Comment: @Lambie Read again.

Comment: Your second version is syntactically invalid. The first version is fine, but it could also be written as two sentences: *Should I send it before June? Or should I wait?* (***if** and **only** if* you imagine there being a noticeable pause before ***or*** - and "rising intonation" on ***June*** to unambiguously identify that as a question in its own right).

Comment: @FumbleFingers This should be an answer.

Comment: Biblasia has made effectively the same point, I think.

Comment: Yes, 2) is agrammatical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be as in your first example:

*Should I send it before June, or should I wait?*

This is because the "or" is joining two equal, independent clauses.  The second clause cannot be treated as an embedded question in this case because it is a question in its own right.

A single sentence should ordinarily have only one question (unless quoting a question in a question, i.e. with quotation marks).  But this is actually two sentences joined by a conjunction, so each one is permitted to have its own question.

Comment: “Or” is a disjunction, not a conjunction. At least in logic. Is it called “conjunction” in grammar?

Comment: Yes, "or" is called a conjunction.  Look it up in a dictionary.  That is its part of speech, unless one uses "OR" as a noun, e.g. an electronics "OR" gate, or to reference a boolean operator in logic.

Comment: Didn’t know that! You taught me two things today! Thanks!

Comment: More specifically, it can be called a _coordinating conjunction_, because it maintains equality between the two things it joins (as opposed to a _subordinating conjunction_ in which one element becomes subordinate to the other).

Comment: Oh, I remember that from high school! Haha. They should make naming consistent across grammar and logic.